# Getting the sum for all of the object retrieve from SharePoint API

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sum

```
  .subscribe((dataTotal) => {
    console.log(dataTotal)
    this.toGetHourData=dataTotal;
    
    const AssociateArray = []
    AssociateArray.push({dataTotal : Number})

    let associateSum: number = 0;
    AssociateArray.forEach(a => associateSum += a.value);
    console.log(associateSum);
    },
```

This is my code. I have pushed all of the object into an array. but when i try to sum it up. the console log a NaN.

p.s: this is my first time with stackoverflow

Comment: You can try out in TS Playground that `{dataTotal : Number}` is a type declaration that actually returns `{}`

Comment: Can you add what is logged to the console?

Comment: The log shown NaN since i pulled along null value when im implementing the API. after cleaning up the value retrieved. I can generate the sum that i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code

**1. Incorrect type declaration**

You have declared `dataTotal : Number` For types you need to use `number` not `Number` hence `dataTotal : number`

**2. You are adding a type to an array!**

Consider the code `AssociateArray.push({dataTotal : Number})`. `{dataTotal : Number}` is basically a type so you are pushing an empty type to the array...

**3. You can use other means to sum e.g using `reduce`**

With these in mind you can change your code to

```typescript
  .subscribe((dataTotal) => {
    this.toGetHourData = dataTotal;
    let associateSum: number = dataTotal.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next.value , 0);
    console.log(associateSum);
  }
```

Comment: it works. i stop using array and directly calculate all the object/value retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
  .subscribe((dataTotal) => {
    console.log(dataTotal)
    this.toGetHourData=dataTotal;

    var clean = []
    var totalnum = 0;

    var associateArray = dataTotal
    associateArray.forEach(element => {
      if (element.strTotalAssociates !== NaN) {
        clean.push(element)
        console.log(element)
        totalnum += element.strTotalAssociates;
        console.log(totalnum)
      }
    });
```

this is the answer that me and my colleague came up with and its work.